# python 3 read csv UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: csv, python-unicode, python-3.6

I have a very simple bit of code that takes in a CVS and puts it into a 2D array. It runs fine on Python2 but in Python3 I get the error below. Looking through the documentation,I think I need to use **.decode()** Could someone please explain how to use it in the context of my code and why I don't need to do anything in Python2

> Error: 
>   line 21, in 
>       for row in datareader:
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 5002: invalid start byte

```
import csv 
import sys 

fullTable = sys.argv[1]

datareader = csv.reader(open(fullTable, 'r'), delimiter=',') 
full_table = [] 
for row in datareader:
        full_table.append(row)

print(full_table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open(argv[1], encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

CSV contained characters where were not UTF-8 which seemed like the default. I am however surprised that python2 dealt with this issue without any problems.